# google analytics regular expression filter to count the number of keywords

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Im trying to figure out a regular expression in google analytics to count the number of words in onsite search terms. The problem I have is that my onsite keywords are a single string containing + which split the words. For example hot+water+bottle. This would obviously be a three word keyphrase. storage+box would be a 2 word keyphrase. I can get all words containing + to indicate more than word was used but I can't for the life of me show all queries containing 2 words or 3 words etc. Can anyone help?

Comment: Mb you can just count number of `+` char in the string?

Answer (score 0):

a two-word query would have at least 1 "+", thus I think the following regex will give you anything with 1 or more "+"

```
.*\+.*
```

.* = any number of characters
+ = the plus sign

so the pattern is (any number of characters)(plus)(any number of characters)

Comment: Hey XTOTHEL that works a treat when combined with exclude logic as well. I can include 2 word keyword phrases but exclude three word phrases etc. Thanks very much.